# Multiple svg on a page with not unique id for filters

Tags: css

I'm trying to show a hovered icon on hover.
I've added rules

```
.downloads-documentation__image:hover > svg:nth-child(1) {display:none;}
.downloads-documentation__image:hover > svg:nth-child(2) {display:block;}
```

It works on the first item in a list, but when I hover the second item it doesn't show hovered icon but hide hovered and not hovered icons.

In dev tools hovered element has `display:block` but i see no icon on hover.

```css
*{outline:none;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
ul,li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
a{text-decoration:none;}
a{text-decoration:none;color:#00D3FF;}
.downloads-documentation__list{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__list{max-width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
}
.downloads-documentation__item{position:relative;width:calc(100% / 12 * 3 - 0px * 2);margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__item{width:calc(100% / 12 * 6 - 0px * 2);margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:30px;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px){
.downloads-documentation__item{width:calc(100% / 12 * 12 - 0px * 2);margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;}
}
.downloads-documentation__item::before,.downloads-documentation__item::after{content:'';background-color:rgba(36, 171, 146, 0.3);position:absolute;width:1px;height:60px;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);transform:translateY(-50%);}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__item::before,.downloads-documentation__item::after{height:100px;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__item::before,.downloads-documentation__item::after{height:100px;}
}
.downloads-documentation__item::before{left:0;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px){
.downloads-documentation__item::before{display:none;}
}
.downloads-documentation__item::after{right:0;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.downloads-documentation__item::after{bottom:-18px;top:auto;right:auto;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, 0);transform:translate(-50%, 0);height:2px;width:100%;max-width:6rem;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){
.downloads-documentation__item:first-child:before{display:none;}
.downloads-documentation__item:last-child:after{display:none;}
}
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__item:nth-child(2n-1):before{display:none;}
.downloads-documentation__item:nth-child(2n):after{display:none;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px){
.downloads-documentation__item:last-child:after{display:none;}
}
.downloads-documentation__reference{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__reference{font-size:16px;}
}
.downloads-documentation__image{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;width:90px;height:80px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.downloads-documentation__image svg{-webkit-transition:0.2s;transition:0.2s;}
.downloads-documentation__image svg:nth-child(1){display:block;}
.downloads-documentation__image svg:nth-child(2){display:none;}
.downloads-documentation__image:hover{-webkit-transition:0.2s;transition:0.2s;}
.downloads-documentation__image:hover svg:nth-child(1){display:none;}
.downloads-documentation__image:hover svg:nth-child(2){display:block;}
```

```html
<ul class="downloads-documentation__list">
                            <li class="downloads-documentation__item">
                    <a class="downloads-documentation__reference" id="item_4" href="" target="_blank">
                        <div class="downloads-documentation__image">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="82" height="70" viewBox="0 0 82 70">
    <g fill="#05E2C2" fill-rule="nonzero">
        <path d="M69.149 10H12.85C11.28 10 10 11.295 10 12.887v37.346c0 1.592 1.28 2.887 2.851 2.887h19.177l-1.42 5.037H26.44a.916.916 0 0 0-.91.921c0 .51.408.922.91.922H55.56c.503 0 .91-.413.91-.922a.916.916 0 0 0-.91-.921h-4.166l-1.421-5.037h19.177c1.572 0 2.851-1.295 2.851-2.887V12.887C72 11.295 70.72 10 69.149 10zM49.5 58.157h-17l1.421-5.037H48.08l1.421 5.037zm20.68-7.924c0 .576-.463 1.044-1.031 1.044H12.85a1.039 1.039 0 0 1-1.031-1.044V12.887c0-.576.463-1.044 1.031-1.044H69.15c.568 0 1.031.468 1.031 1.044v37.346z"></path>
        <path d="M67.094 14H14.906a.91.91 0 0 0-.906.915v33.17a.91.91 0 0 0 .906.915h52.188c.5 0 .906-.41.906-.915v-33.17a.91.91 0 0 0-.906-.915zm-.34 1.138v3H15.246v-3h51.508zM15.246 48.004v-29h51.508v29H15.246zM17.75 17.5a.753.753 0 0 1-.75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75zm2 0a.753.753 0 0 1-.75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75zm2 0a.753.753 0 0 1-.75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75z"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width=".6" d="M50 33.385h-.872v-3.973c0-.952-.783-1.727-1.745-1.727H46.2l-1.209-2.152a1.049 1.049 0 0 0-1.424-.402l-4.64 2.554h-5.183c-.962 0-1.745.775-1.745 1.727v11.86c0 .953.783 1.728 1.745 1.728h13.638c.962 0 1.745-.775 1.745-1.727V37.79H50v-4.405zm-2.617-5.009c.537 0 .976.404 1.035.921h-1.311l-.517-.92h.793zm-3.475-2.642a.357.357 0 0 1 .474.134l1.926 3.429h-8.872l6.472-3.563zm4.522 15.539c0 .571-.47 1.036-1.047 1.036H33.745a1.043 1.043 0 0 1-1.047-1.036v-11.86c0-.572.47-1.037 1.047-1.037h3.928L36 29.297h-2.037a.347.347 0 0 0-.35.346c0 .19.157.345.35.345H48.43v3.397h-2.552c-1.185 0-2.15.955-2.15 2.128v.149c0 1.173.965 2.128 2.15 2.128h2.552v3.483zm.872-4.174h-3.424c-.8 0-1.452-.645-1.452-1.437v-.149c0-.792.651-1.437 1.452-1.437h3.424v3.023z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="82" height="70" viewBox="0 0 82 70">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="151.6%" height="164%" x="-25.8%" y="-32%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.7 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="#05E2C2" fill-rule="nonzero" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(10 10)">
        <path d="M59.149 0H2.85C1.28 0 0 1.295 0 2.887v37.346c0 1.592 1.28 2.887 2.851 2.887h19.177l-1.42 5.037H16.44a.916.916 0 0 0-.91.921c0 .51.408.922.91.922H45.56c.503 0 .91-.413.91-.922a.916.916 0 0 0-.91-.921h-4.166l-1.421-5.037h19.177c1.572 0 2.851-1.295 2.851-2.887V2.887C62 1.295 60.72 0 59.149 0zM39.5 48.157h-17l1.421-5.037H38.08l1.421 5.037zm20.68-7.924c0 .576-.463 1.044-1.031 1.044H2.85a1.039 1.039 0 0 1-1.031-1.044V2.887c0-.576.463-1.044 1.031-1.044H59.15c.568 0 1.031.468 1.031 1.044v37.346z"></path>
        <path d="M57.094 4H4.906A.91.91 0 0 0 4 4.915v33.17a.91.91 0 0 0 .906.915h52.188c.5 0 .906-.41.906-.915V4.915A.91.91 0 0 0 57.094 4zm-.34 1.138v3H5.246v-3h51.508zM5.246 38.004v-29h51.508v29H5.246zM7.75 7.5A.753.753 0 0 1 7 6.75.753.753 0 0 1 7.75 6a.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75zm2 0A.753.753 0 0 1 9 6.75.753.753 0 0 1 9.75 6a.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75zm2 0a.753.753 0 0 1-.75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75z"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width=".6" d="M40 23.385h-.872v-3.973c0-.952-.783-1.727-1.745-1.727H36.2l-1.209-2.152a1.049 1.049 0 0 0-1.424-.402l-4.64 2.554h-5.183c-.962 0-1.745.775-1.745 1.727v11.86c0 .953.783 1.728 1.745 1.728h13.638c.962 0 1.745-.775 1.745-1.727V27.79H40v-4.405zm-2.617-5.009c.537 0 .976.404 1.035.921h-1.311l-.517-.92h.793zm-3.475-2.642a.357.357 0 0 1 .474.134l1.926 3.429h-8.872l6.472-3.563zm4.522 15.539c0 .571-.47 1.036-1.047 1.036H23.745a1.043 1.043 0 0 1-1.047-1.036v-11.86c0-.572.47-1.037 1.047-1.037h3.928L26 19.297h-2.037a.347.347 0 0 0-.35.346c0 .19.157.345.35.345H38.43v3.397h-2.552c-1.185 0-2.15.955-2.15 2.128v.149c0 1.173.965 2.128 2.15 2.128h2.552v3.483zm.872-4.174h-3.424c-.8 0-1.452-.645-1.452-1.437v-.149c0-.792.651-1.437 1.452-1.437h3.424v3.023z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                        </div>
                        Desktop Wallet App
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="downloads-documentation__item">
                    <a class="downloads-documentation__reference" id="item_1" href="" target="_blank">
                        <div class="downloads-documentation__image">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="76" viewBox="0 0 70 76">
    <g fill="#05E2C2" fill-rule="nonzero">
        <path d="M58.925 10H20.159a1.088 1.088 0 0 0-.767.305c-.205.198-.32.468-.323.75l-.259 42.857h-7.714a1.083 1.083 0 0 0-.77.3 1.052 1.052 0 0 0-.326.75v2.253c0 4.708 3.635 8.562 8.174 8.776v.006h32.698v-.015c.272.01.368.018.545.018C56.141 66 60 62.06 60 57.215v-46.19a1.016 1.016 0 0 0-.316-.738 1.044 1.044 0 0 0-.759-.286zM18.571 63.85c-3.521 0-6.391-2.974-6.391-6.634V56.06h30.654v1.155a8.896 8.896 0 0 0 3.012 6.634H18.571zm39.25-6.634c0 3.66-2.883 6.637-6.404 6.637-3.522 0-6.403-2.977-6.403-6.637v-2.253a1.008 1.008 0 0 0-.292-.745 1.034 1.034 0 0 0-.748-.305H20.99l.252-41.763H57.82v45.066z"></path>
        <path d="M27.112 23h25.776c.614 0 1.112-.448 1.112-1s-.498-1-1.112-1H27.112c-.614 0-1.112.448-1.112 1s.498 1 1.112 1zM27.112 19h25.776c.614 0 1.112-.448 1.112-1s-.498-1-1.112-1H27.112c-.614 0-1.112.448-1.112 1s.498 1 1.112 1z"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width=".8" d="M48 37.385h-.872v-3.973c0-.952-.783-1.727-1.745-1.727H44.2l-1.209-2.152a1.049 1.049 0 0 0-1.424-.402l-4.64 2.554h-5.183c-.962 0-1.745.775-1.745 1.727v11.86c0 .953.783 1.728 1.745 1.728h13.638c.962 0 1.745-.775 1.745-1.727V41.79H48v-4.405zm-2.617-5.009c.537 0 .976.404 1.035.921h-1.311l-.517-.92h.793zm-3.475-2.642a.357.357 0 0 1 .474.134l1.926 3.429h-8.872l6.472-3.563zm4.522 15.539c0 .571-.47 1.036-1.047 1.036H31.745a1.043 1.043 0 0 1-1.047-1.036v-11.86c0-.572.47-1.037 1.047-1.037h3.928L34 33.297h-2.037a.347.347 0 0 0-.35.346c0 .19.157.345.35.345H46.43v3.397h-2.552c-1.185 0-2.15.955-2.15 2.128v.149c0 1.173.965 2.128 2.15 2.128h2.552v3.483zm.872-4.174h-3.424c-.8 0-1.452-.645-1.452-1.437v-.149c0-.792.651-1.437 1.452-1.437h3.424v3.023z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="76" viewBox="0 0 70 76">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="164%" height="157.1%" x="-32%" y="-28.6%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.7 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="#05E2C2" fill-rule="nonzero" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(10 10)">
        <path d="M48.925 0H10.159a1.088 1.088 0 0 0-.767.305c-.205.198-.32.468-.323.75L8.81 43.913H1.096a1.083 1.083 0 0 0-.77.3 1.052 1.052 0 0 0-.326.75v2.253c0 4.708 3.635 8.562 8.174 8.776v.006h32.698v-.015c.272.01.368.018.545.018C46.141 56 50 52.06 50 47.215V1.025a1.016 1.016 0 0 0-.316-.738 1.044 1.044 0 0 0-.759-.286zM8.571 53.85c-3.521 0-6.391-2.974-6.391-6.634V46.06h30.654v1.155a8.896 8.896 0 0 0 3.012 6.634H8.571zm39.25-6.634c0 3.66-2.883 6.637-6.404 6.637-3.522 0-6.403-2.977-6.403-6.637v-2.253a1.008 1.008 0 0 0-.292-.745 1.034 1.034 0 0 0-.748-.305H10.99l.252-41.763H47.82v45.066z"></path>
        <path d="M17.112 13h25.776c.614 0 1.112-.448 1.112-1s-.498-1-1.112-1H17.112c-.614 0-1.112.448-1.112 1s.498 1 1.112 1zM17.112 9h25.776C43.502 9 44 8.552 44 8s-.498-1-1.112-1H17.112C16.498 7 16 7.448 16 8s.498 1 1.112 1z"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width=".8" d="M38 27.385h-.872v-3.973c0-.952-.783-1.727-1.745-1.727H34.2l-1.209-2.152a1.049 1.049 0 0 0-1.424-.402l-4.64 2.554h-5.183c-.962 0-1.745.775-1.745 1.727v11.86c0 .953.783 1.728 1.745 1.728h13.638c.962 0 1.745-.775 1.745-1.727V31.79H38v-4.405zm-2.617-5.009c.537 0 .976.404 1.035.921h-1.311l-.517-.92h.793zm-3.475-2.642a.357.357 0 0 1 .474.134l1.926 3.429h-8.872l6.472-3.563zm4.522 15.539c0 .571-.47 1.036-1.047 1.036H21.745a1.043 1.043 0 0 1-1.047-1.036v-11.86c0-.572.47-1.037 1.047-1.037h3.928L24 23.297h-2.037a.347.347 0 0 0-.35.346c0 .19.157.345.35.345H36.43v3.397h-2.552c-1.185 0-2.15.955-2.15 2.128v.149c0 1.173.965 2.128 2.15 2.128h2.552v3.483zm.872-4.174h-3.424c-.8 0-1.452-.645-1.452-1.437v-.149c0-.792.651-1.437 1.452-1.437h3.424v3.023z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                        </div>
                        Command Line Wallet
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="downloads-documentation__item">
                    <a class="downloads-documentation__reference" id="item_2" href="" target="_blank">
                        <div class="downloads-documentation__image">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="88" height="62" viewBox="0 0 88 62">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width="2" d="M73.393 11.048H14.25c-1.788 0-3.25 1.436-3.25 3.19v31.106c0 1.753 1.462 3.189 3.25 3.189h6.118c-.015.091-.03.184-.03.278 0 .908.756 1.65 1.68 1.65h16.624c.924 0 1.677-.742 1.677-1.65 0-.094-.01-.187-.027-.278h33.1c1.788 0 3.25-1.436 3.25-3.19V14.24c0-1.755-1.462-3.191-3.25-3.191"></path>
        <g fill="#05E2C2">
            <path d="M30.001 43c-.544 0-.99-.37-.99-.818V17.818c0-.45.446-.818.99-.818.542 0 .988.368.988.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.988.818M33.999 43c-.542 0-.988-.37-.988-.818V17.818c0-.45.446-.818.988-.818.544 0 .99.368.99.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.99.818M38 43c-.544 0-.988-.37-.988-.818V17.818c0-.45.444-.818.988-.818.542 0 .988.368.988.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.988.818"></path>
        </g>
        <g fill="#05E2C2">
            <path d="M25 19.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5.001 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5.001 0M25 29.5c0 1.382-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5a2.497 2.497 0 0 1-2.5-2.5 2.499 2.499 0 1 1 5 0M20 40.5c0-1.382 1.118-2.5 2.5-2.5a2.499 2.499 0 1 1 0 5c-1.382 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5"></path>
        </g>
        <path fill="#05E2C2" d="M16 15.001a1 1 0 0 1-2 0 .999.999 0 1 1 2 0M16 45a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0M74 15.001a1 1 0 0 1-2 0 .999.999 0 1 1 2 0M74 45a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0M61 30.001A2.998 2.998 0 0 1 58.001 33a2.999 2.999 0 1 1 0-6A3 3 0 0 1 61 30.001"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" d="M72 30c0 7.731-6.269 14-14 14s-14-6.269-14-14 6.269-14 14-14 14 6.269 14 14z"></path>
        <path fill="#05E2C2" d="M57.97 25.307c.952 0 1.84.246 2.594.664l.436-4.48C61 20.245 59.42 19 58.026 19h-2.741c-2.062 0-4.056 2.016-2.987 3.59L55.326 26a5.313 5.313 0 0 1 2.645-.693M58.03 34.694a5.327 5.327 0 0 1-2.594-.665L55 38.508C55 39.755 56.578 41 57.974 41h2.742c2.062 0 4.056-2.015 2.985-3.59L60.675 34a5.321 5.321 0 0 1-2.646.694M53.306 30.03c0-.954.246-1.841.665-2.596L49.492 27C48.246 27 47 28.578 47 29.973v2.744c0 2.06 2.015 4.054 3.59 2.985L54 32.674a5.31 5.31 0 0 1-.694-2.644M62.693 29.97c0 .954-.245 1.841-.664 2.594l4.479.436C67.754 33 69 31.422 69 30.026v-2.742c0-2.062-2.017-4.055-3.59-2.985L62 27.325a5.32 5.32 0 0 1 .693 2.645"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="88" height="62" viewBox="0 0 88 62">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="151.5%" height="185%" x="-25.8%" y="-42.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.7 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(11 11)">
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width="2" d="M62.393.048H3.25C1.462.048 0 1.484 0 3.238v31.106c0 1.753 1.462 3.189 3.25 3.189h6.118c-.015.091-.03.184-.03.278 0 .908.756 1.65 1.68 1.65h16.624c.924 0 1.677-.742 1.677-1.65 0-.094-.01-.187-.027-.278h33.1c1.788 0 3.25-1.436 3.25-3.19V3.24c0-1.755-1.462-3.191-3.25-3.191"></path>
        <g fill="#05E2C2">
            <path d="M19.001 32c-.544 0-.99-.37-.99-.818V6.818c0-.45.446-.818.99-.818.542 0 .988.368.988.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.988.818M22.999 32c-.542 0-.988-.37-.988-.818V6.818c0-.45.446-.818.988-.818.544 0 .99.368.99.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.99.818M27 32c-.544 0-.988-.37-.988-.818V6.818c0-.45.444-.818.988-.818.542 0 .988.368.988.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.988.818"></path>
        </g>
        <g fill="#05E2C2">
            <path d="M14 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5.001 0A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 14 8.5M14 18.5c0 1.382-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5A2.497 2.497 0 0 1 9 18.5a2.499 2.499 0 1 1 5 0M9 29.5c0-1.382 1.118-2.5 2.5-2.5a2.499 2.499 0 1 1 0 5C10.117 32 9 30.88 9 29.5"></path>
        </g>
        <path fill="#05E2C2" d="M5 4.001a1 1 0 0 1-2 0 .999.999 0 1 1 2 0M5 34a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0M63 4.001a1 1 0 0 1-2 0 .999.999 0 1 1 2 0M63 34a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0M50 19.001A2.998 2.998 0 0 1 47.001 22a2.999 2.999 0 1 1 0-6A3 3 0 0 1 50 19.001"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" d="M61 19c0 7.731-6.269 14-14 14s-14-6.269-14-14S39.269 5 47 5s14 6.269 14 14z"></path>
        <path fill="#05E2C2" d="M46.97 14.307c.952 0 1.84.246 2.594.664l.436-4.48C50 9.245 48.42 8 47.026 8h-2.741c-2.062 0-4.056 2.016-2.987 3.59L44.326 15a5.313 5.313 0 0 1 2.645-.693M47.03 23.694a5.327 5.327 0 0 1-2.594-.665L44 27.508C44 28.755 45.578 30 46.974 30h2.742c2.062 0 4.056-2.015 2.985-3.59L49.675 23a5.321 5.321 0 0 1-2.646.694M42.306 19.03c0-.954.246-1.841.665-2.596L38.492 16C37.246 16 36 17.578 36 18.973v2.744c0 2.06 2.015 4.054 3.59 2.985L43 21.674a5.31 5.31 0 0 1-.694-2.644M51.693 18.97c0 .954-.245 1.841-.664 2.594l4.479.436C56.754 22 58 20.422 58 19.026v-2.742c0-2.062-2.017-4.055-3.59-2.985L51 16.325a5.32 5.32 0 0 1 .693 2.645"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                        </div>
                        GPU cards
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="downloads-documentation__item">
                    <a class="downloads-documentation__reference" id="item_3" href="" target="_blank">
                        <div class="downloads-documentation__image">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="72" viewBox="0 0 75 72">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="164.2%" height="168%" x="-32.1%" y="-34%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.699655813 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#05E2C2" transform="translate(11 11)">
        <circle cx="14.5" cy="7.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="45.5" cy="25.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="7.5" cy="35.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="5" cy="20" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="39" cy="11" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="30" cy="46" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="24" cy="25" r="5" fill="#05E2C2" stroke-width="4"></circle>
        <path stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="2" d="M18.667 14L22 20M9.208 22.213L19 25M36 14l-7 7.775M38 26.75H28M28 41.768l-3-12.652M14.318 32.286l6.47-4.048"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="72" viewBox="0 0 75 72">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="164.2%" height="168%" x="-32.1%" y="-34%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.699655813 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#05E2C2" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(11 11)">
        <circle cx="14.5" cy="7.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="45.5" cy="25.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="7.5" cy="35.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="5" cy="20" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="39" cy="11" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="30" cy="46" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="24" cy="25" r="5" fill="#05E2C2" stroke-width="4"></circle>
        <path stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="2" d="M18.667 14L22 20M9.208 22.213L19 25M36 14l-7 7.775M38 26.75H28M28 41.768l-3-12.652M14.318 32.286l6.47-4.048"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                        </div>
                        Command Line Node
                    </a>
                </li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filters are the problem. The filter has to be defined inside the `<svg>` and `<defs>`, but can't be named the same it seems. Renaming all the `#a` filters to `#a`, `#b`, `#c` and so on seems to work. That also explains why the first svg works, but all others not: the filter with name `a` is already defined, so the browser tries to fetch that and fails. See demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/wfhv2b31/ (in the demo I renamed the second and third, but not the fourth, hence why the last SVG doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

ihav done similar thing here `hypergiant.com`, you have to use bit of position for second svg child, hope this will solve your issue. I used `opacity` instead display.

```css
*{outline:none;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
ul,li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
a{text-decoration:none;}
a{text-decoration:none;color:#00D3FF;}
.downloads-documentation__list{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__list{max-width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
}
.downloads-documentation__item{position:relative;width:calc(100% / 12 * 3 - 0px * 2);margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__item{width:calc(100% / 12 * 6 - 0px * 2);margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:30px;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px){
.downloads-documentation__item{width:calc(100% / 12 * 12 - 0px * 2);margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;}
}
.downloads-documentation__item::before,.downloads-documentation__item::after{content:'';background-color:rgba(36, 171, 146, 0.3);position:absolute;width:1px;height:60px;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);transform:translateY(-50%);}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__item::before,.downloads-documentation__item::after{height:100px;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__item::before,.downloads-documentation__item::after{height:100px;}
}
.downloads-documentation__item::before{left:0;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px){
.downloads-documentation__item::before{display:none;}
}
.downloads-documentation__item::after{right:0;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.downloads-documentation__item::after{bottom:-18px;top:auto;right:auto;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, 0);transform:translate(-50%, 0);height:2px;width:100%;max-width:6rem;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){
.downloads-documentation__item:first-child:before{display:none;}
.downloads-documentation__item:last-child:after{display:none;}
}
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__item:nth-child(2n-1):before{display:none;}
.downloads-documentation__item:nth-child(2n):after{display:none;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px){
.downloads-documentation__item:last-child:after{display:none;}
}
.downloads-documentation__reference{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
.downloads-documentation__reference{font-size:16px;}
}
.downloads-documentation__image{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;width:90px;height:80px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.downloads-documentation__image svg{-webkit-transition:0.2s;transition:0.2s;}
.downloads-documentation__image svg{display:block;}

.downloads-documentation__image:hover{-webkit-transition:0.2s;transition:0.2s;}
.downloads-documentation__image svg + svg{opacity:0; position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:-39px; bottom:0; margin:auto;}
.downloads-documentation__image:hover > svg:first-child{opacity:0;}
.downloads-documentation__image:hover svg + svg{opacity:1;}
```

```html
<ul class="downloads-documentation__list">
                            <li class="downloads-documentation__item">
                    <a class="downloads-documentation__reference" id="item_4" href="" target="_blank">
                        <div class="downloads-documentation__image">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="82" height="70" viewBox="0 0 82 70">
    <g fill="#05E2C2" fill-rule="nonzero">
        <path d="M69.149 10H12.85C11.28 10 10 11.295 10 12.887v37.346c0 1.592 1.28 2.887 2.851 2.887h19.177l-1.42 5.037H26.44a.916.916 0 0 0-.91.921c0 .51.408.922.91.922H55.56c.503 0 .91-.413.91-.922a.916.916 0 0 0-.91-.921h-4.166l-1.421-5.037h19.177c1.572 0 2.851-1.295 2.851-2.887V12.887C72 11.295 70.72 10 69.149 10zM49.5 58.157h-17l1.421-5.037H48.08l1.421 5.037zm20.68-7.924c0 .576-.463 1.044-1.031 1.044H12.85a1.039 1.039 0 0 1-1.031-1.044V12.887c0-.576.463-1.044 1.031-1.044H69.15c.568 0 1.031.468 1.031 1.044v37.346z"></path>
        <path d="M67.094 14H14.906a.91.91 0 0 0-.906.915v33.17a.91.91 0 0 0 .906.915h52.188c.5 0 .906-.41.906-.915v-33.17a.91.91 0 0 0-.906-.915zm-.34 1.138v3H15.246v-3h51.508zM15.246 48.004v-29h51.508v29H15.246zM17.75 17.5a.753.753 0 0 1-.75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75zm2 0a.753.753 0 0 1-.75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75zm2 0a.753.753 0 0 1-.75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75z"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width=".6" d="M50 33.385h-.872v-3.973c0-.952-.783-1.727-1.745-1.727H46.2l-1.209-2.152a1.049 1.049 0 0 0-1.424-.402l-4.64 2.554h-5.183c-.962 0-1.745.775-1.745 1.727v11.86c0 .953.783 1.728 1.745 1.728h13.638c.962 0 1.745-.775 1.745-1.727V37.79H50v-4.405zm-2.617-5.009c.537 0 .976.404 1.035.921h-1.311l-.517-.92h.793zm-3.475-2.642a.357.357 0 0 1 .474.134l1.926 3.429h-8.872l6.472-3.563zm4.522 15.539c0 .571-.47 1.036-1.047 1.036H33.745a1.043 1.043 0 0 1-1.047-1.036v-11.86c0-.572.47-1.037 1.047-1.037h3.928L36 29.297h-2.037a.347.347 0 0 0-.35.346c0 .19.157.345.35.345H48.43v3.397h-2.552c-1.185 0-2.15.955-2.15 2.128v.149c0 1.173.965 2.128 2.15 2.128h2.552v3.483zm.872-4.174h-3.424c-.8 0-1.452-.645-1.452-1.437v-.149c0-.792.651-1.437 1.452-1.437h3.424v3.023z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="82" height="70" viewBox="0 0 82 70">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="151.6%" height="164%" x="-25.8%" y="-32%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.7 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="#05E2C2" fill-rule="nonzero" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(10 10)">
        <path d="M59.149 0H2.85C1.28 0 0 1.295 0 2.887v37.346c0 1.592 1.28 2.887 2.851 2.887h19.177l-1.42 5.037H16.44a.916.916 0 0 0-.91.921c0 .51.408.922.91.922H45.56c.503 0 .91-.413.91-.922a.916.916 0 0 0-.91-.921h-4.166l-1.421-5.037h19.177c1.572 0 2.851-1.295 2.851-2.887V2.887C62 1.295 60.72 0 59.149 0zM39.5 48.157h-17l1.421-5.037H38.08l1.421 5.037zm20.68-7.924c0 .576-.463 1.044-1.031 1.044H2.85a1.039 1.039 0 0 1-1.031-1.044V2.887c0-.576.463-1.044 1.031-1.044H59.15c.568 0 1.031.468 1.031 1.044v37.346z"></path>
        <path d="M57.094 4H4.906A.91.91 0 0 0 4 4.915v33.17a.91.91 0 0 0 .906.915h52.188c.5 0 .906-.41.906-.915V4.915A.91.91 0 0 0 57.094 4zm-.34 1.138v3H5.246v-3h51.508zM5.246 38.004v-29h51.508v29H5.246zM7.75 7.5A.753.753 0 0 1 7 6.75.753.753 0 0 1 7.75 6a.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75zm2 0A.753.753 0 0 1 9 6.75.753.753 0 0 1 9.75 6a.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75zm2 0a.753.753 0 0 1-.75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75-.75.753.753 0 0 1 .75.75.753.753 0 0 1-.75.75z"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width=".6" d="M40 23.385h-.872v-3.973c0-.952-.783-1.727-1.745-1.727H36.2l-1.209-2.152a1.049 1.049 0 0 0-1.424-.402l-4.64 2.554h-5.183c-.962 0-1.745.775-1.745 1.727v11.86c0 .953.783 1.728 1.745 1.728h13.638c.962 0 1.745-.775 1.745-1.727V27.79H40v-4.405zm-2.617-5.009c.537 0 .976.404 1.035.921h-1.311l-.517-.92h.793zm-3.475-2.642a.357.357 0 0 1 .474.134l1.926 3.429h-8.872l6.472-3.563zm4.522 15.539c0 .571-.47 1.036-1.047 1.036H23.745a1.043 1.043 0 0 1-1.047-1.036v-11.86c0-.572.47-1.037 1.047-1.037h3.928L26 19.297h-2.037a.347.347 0 0 0-.35.346c0 .19.157.345.35.345H38.43v3.397h-2.552c-1.185 0-2.15.955-2.15 2.128v.149c0 1.173.965 2.128 2.15 2.128h2.552v3.483zm.872-4.174h-3.424c-.8 0-1.452-.645-1.452-1.437v-.149c0-.792.651-1.437 1.452-1.437h3.424v3.023z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                        </div>
                        Desktop Wallet App
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="downloads-documentation__item">
                    <a class="downloads-documentation__reference" id="item_1" href="" target="_blank">
                        <div class="downloads-documentation__image">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="76" viewBox="0 0 70 76">
    <g fill="#05E2C2" fill-rule="nonzero">
        <path d="M58.925 10H20.159a1.088 1.088 0 0 0-.767.305c-.205.198-.32.468-.323.75l-.259 42.857h-7.714a1.083 1.083 0 0 0-.77.3 1.052 1.052 0 0 0-.326.75v2.253c0 4.708 3.635 8.562 8.174 8.776v.006h32.698v-.015c.272.01.368.018.545.018C56.141 66 60 62.06 60 57.215v-46.19a1.016 1.016 0 0 0-.316-.738 1.044 1.044 0 0 0-.759-.286zM18.571 63.85c-3.521 0-6.391-2.974-6.391-6.634V56.06h30.654v1.155a8.896 8.896 0 0 0 3.012 6.634H18.571zm39.25-6.634c0 3.66-2.883 6.637-6.404 6.637-3.522 0-6.403-2.977-6.403-6.637v-2.253a1.008 1.008 0 0 0-.292-.745 1.034 1.034 0 0 0-.748-.305H20.99l.252-41.763H57.82v45.066z"></path>
        <path d="M27.112 23h25.776c.614 0 1.112-.448 1.112-1s-.498-1-1.112-1H27.112c-.614 0-1.112.448-1.112 1s.498 1 1.112 1zM27.112 19h25.776c.614 0 1.112-.448 1.112-1s-.498-1-1.112-1H27.112c-.614 0-1.112.448-1.112 1s.498 1 1.112 1z"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width=".8" d="M48 37.385h-.872v-3.973c0-.952-.783-1.727-1.745-1.727H44.2l-1.209-2.152a1.049 1.049 0 0 0-1.424-.402l-4.64 2.554h-5.183c-.962 0-1.745.775-1.745 1.727v11.86c0 .953.783 1.728 1.745 1.728h13.638c.962 0 1.745-.775 1.745-1.727V41.79H48v-4.405zm-2.617-5.009c.537 0 .976.404 1.035.921h-1.311l-.517-.92h.793zm-3.475-2.642a.357.357 0 0 1 .474.134l1.926 3.429h-8.872l6.472-3.563zm4.522 15.539c0 .571-.47 1.036-1.047 1.036H31.745a1.043 1.043 0 0 1-1.047-1.036v-11.86c0-.572.47-1.037 1.047-1.037h3.928L34 33.297h-2.037a.347.347 0 0 0-.35.346c0 .19.157.345.35.345H46.43v3.397h-2.552c-1.185 0-2.15.955-2.15 2.128v.149c0 1.173.965 2.128 2.15 2.128h2.552v3.483zm.872-4.174h-3.424c-.8 0-1.452-.645-1.452-1.437v-.149c0-.792.651-1.437 1.452-1.437h3.424v3.023z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="76" viewBox="0 0 70 76">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="164%" height="157.1%" x="-32%" y="-28.6%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.7 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="#05E2C2" fill-rule="nonzero" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(10 10)">
        <path d="M48.925 0H10.159a1.088 1.088 0 0 0-.767.305c-.205.198-.32.468-.323.75L8.81 43.913H1.096a1.083 1.083 0 0 0-.77.3 1.052 1.052 0 0 0-.326.75v2.253c0 4.708 3.635 8.562 8.174 8.776v.006h32.698v-.015c.272.01.368.018.545.018C46.141 56 50 52.06 50 47.215V1.025a1.016 1.016 0 0 0-.316-.738 1.044 1.044 0 0 0-.759-.286zM8.571 53.85c-3.521 0-6.391-2.974-6.391-6.634V46.06h30.654v1.155a8.896 8.896 0 0 0 3.012 6.634H8.571zm39.25-6.634c0 3.66-2.883 6.637-6.404 6.637-3.522 0-6.403-2.977-6.403-6.637v-2.253a1.008 1.008 0 0 0-.292-.745 1.034 1.034 0 0 0-.748-.305H10.99l.252-41.763H47.82v45.066z"></path>
        <path d="M17.112 13h25.776c.614 0 1.112-.448 1.112-1s-.498-1-1.112-1H17.112c-.614 0-1.112.448-1.112 1s.498 1 1.112 1zM17.112 9h25.776C43.502 9 44 8.552 44 8s-.498-1-1.112-1H17.112C16.498 7 16 7.448 16 8s.498 1 1.112 1z"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width=".8" d="M38 27.385h-.872v-3.973c0-.952-.783-1.727-1.745-1.727H34.2l-1.209-2.152a1.049 1.049 0 0 0-1.424-.402l-4.64 2.554h-5.183c-.962 0-1.745.775-1.745 1.727v11.86c0 .953.783 1.728 1.745 1.728h13.638c.962 0 1.745-.775 1.745-1.727V31.79H38v-4.405zm-2.617-5.009c.537 0 .976.404 1.035.921h-1.311l-.517-.92h.793zm-3.475-2.642a.357.357 0 0 1 .474.134l1.926 3.429h-8.872l6.472-3.563zm4.522 15.539c0 .571-.47 1.036-1.047 1.036H21.745a1.043 1.043 0 0 1-1.047-1.036v-11.86c0-.572.47-1.037 1.047-1.037h3.928L24 23.297h-2.037a.347.347 0 0 0-.35.346c0 .19.157.345.35.345H36.43v3.397h-2.552c-1.185 0-2.15.955-2.15 2.128v.149c0 1.173.965 2.128 2.15 2.128h2.552v3.483zm.872-4.174h-3.424c-.8 0-1.452-.645-1.452-1.437v-.149c0-.792.651-1.437 1.452-1.437h3.424v3.023z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                        </div>
                        Command Line Wallet
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="downloads-documentation__item">
                    <a class="downloads-documentation__reference" id="item_2" href="" target="_blank">
                        <div class="downloads-documentation__image">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="88" height="62" viewBox="0 0 88 62">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width="2" d="M73.393 11.048H14.25c-1.788 0-3.25 1.436-3.25 3.19v31.106c0 1.753 1.462 3.189 3.25 3.189h6.118c-.015.091-.03.184-.03.278 0 .908.756 1.65 1.68 1.65h16.624c.924 0 1.677-.742 1.677-1.65 0-.094-.01-.187-.027-.278h33.1c1.788 0 3.25-1.436 3.25-3.19V14.24c0-1.755-1.462-3.191-3.25-3.191"></path>
        <g fill="#05E2C2">
            <path d="M30.001 43c-.544 0-.99-.37-.99-.818V17.818c0-.45.446-.818.99-.818.542 0 .988.368.988.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.988.818M33.999 43c-.542 0-.988-.37-.988-.818V17.818c0-.45.446-.818.988-.818.544 0 .99.368.99.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.99.818M38 43c-.544 0-.988-.37-.988-.818V17.818c0-.45.444-.818.988-.818.542 0 .988.368.988.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.988.818"></path>
        </g>
        <g fill="#05E2C2">
            <path d="M25 19.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5.001 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5.001 0M25 29.5c0 1.382-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5a2.497 2.497 0 0 1-2.5-2.5 2.499 2.499 0 1 1 5 0M20 40.5c0-1.382 1.118-2.5 2.5-2.5a2.499 2.499 0 1 1 0 5c-1.382 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5"></path>
        </g>
        <path fill="#05E2C2" d="M16 15.001a1 1 0 0 1-2 0 .999.999 0 1 1 2 0M16 45a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0M74 15.001a1 1 0 0 1-2 0 .999.999 0 1 1 2 0M74 45a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0M61 30.001A2.998 2.998 0 0 1 58.001 33a2.999 2.999 0 1 1 0-6A3 3 0 0 1 61 30.001"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" d="M72 30c0 7.731-6.269 14-14 14s-14-6.269-14-14 6.269-14 14-14 14 6.269 14 14z"></path>
        <path fill="#05E2C2" d="M57.97 25.307c.952 0 1.84.246 2.594.664l.436-4.48C61 20.245 59.42 19 58.026 19h-2.741c-2.062 0-4.056 2.016-2.987 3.59L55.326 26a5.313 5.313 0 0 1 2.645-.693M58.03 34.694a5.327 5.327 0 0 1-2.594-.665L55 38.508C55 39.755 56.578 41 57.974 41h2.742c2.062 0 4.056-2.015 2.985-3.59L60.675 34a5.321 5.321 0 0 1-2.646.694M53.306 30.03c0-.954.246-1.841.665-2.596L49.492 27C48.246 27 47 28.578 47 29.973v2.744c0 2.06 2.015 4.054 3.59 2.985L54 32.674a5.31 5.31 0 0 1-.694-2.644M62.693 29.97c0 .954-.245 1.841-.664 2.594l4.479.436C67.754 33 69 31.422 69 30.026v-2.742c0-2.062-2.017-4.055-3.59-2.985L62 27.325a5.32 5.32 0 0 1 .693 2.645"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="88" height="62" viewBox="0 0 88 62">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="151.5%" height="185%" x="-25.8%" y="-42.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.7 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(11 11)">
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" stroke-width="2" d="M62.393.048H3.25C1.462.048 0 1.484 0 3.238v31.106c0 1.753 1.462 3.189 3.25 3.189h6.118c-.015.091-.03.184-.03.278 0 .908.756 1.65 1.68 1.65h16.624c.924 0 1.677-.742 1.677-1.65 0-.094-.01-.187-.027-.278h33.1c1.788 0 3.25-1.436 3.25-3.19V3.24c0-1.755-1.462-3.191-3.25-3.191"></path>
        <g fill="#05E2C2">
            <path d="M19.001 32c-.544 0-.99-.37-.99-.818V6.818c0-.45.446-.818.99-.818.542 0 .988.368.988.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.988.818M22.999 32c-.542 0-.988-.37-.988-.818V6.818c0-.45.446-.818.988-.818.544 0 .99.368.99.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.99.818M27 32c-.544 0-.988-.37-.988-.818V6.818c0-.45.444-.818.988-.818.542 0 .988.368.988.818v24.364c0 .449-.446.818-.988.818"></path>
        </g>
        <g fill="#05E2C2">
            <path d="M14 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5.001 0A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 14 8.5M14 18.5c0 1.382-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5A2.497 2.497 0 0 1 9 18.5a2.499 2.499 0 1 1 5 0M9 29.5c0-1.382 1.118-2.5 2.5-2.5a2.499 2.499 0 1 1 0 5C10.117 32 9 30.88 9 29.5"></path>
        </g>
        <path fill="#05E2C2" d="M5 4.001a1 1 0 0 1-2 0 .999.999 0 1 1 2 0M5 34a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0M63 4.001a1 1 0 0 1-2 0 .999.999 0 1 1 2 0M63 34a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0M50 19.001A2.998 2.998 0 0 1 47.001 22a2.999 2.999 0 1 1 0-6A3 3 0 0 1 50 19.001"></path>
        <path stroke="#05E2C2" d="M61 19c0 7.731-6.269 14-14 14s-14-6.269-14-14S39.269 5 47 5s14 6.269 14 14z"></path>
        <path fill="#05E2C2" d="M46.97 14.307c.952 0 1.84.246 2.594.664l.436-4.48C50 9.245 48.42 8 47.026 8h-2.741c-2.062 0-4.056 2.016-2.987 3.59L44.326 15a5.313 5.313 0 0 1 2.645-.693M47.03 23.694a5.327 5.327 0 0 1-2.594-.665L44 27.508C44 28.755 45.578 30 46.974 30h2.742c2.062 0 4.056-2.015 2.985-3.59L49.675 23a5.321 5.321 0 0 1-2.646.694M42.306 19.03c0-.954.246-1.841.665-2.596L38.492 16C37.246 16 36 17.578 36 18.973v2.744c0 2.06 2.015 4.054 3.59 2.985L43 21.674a5.31 5.31 0 0 1-.694-2.644M51.693 18.97c0 .954-.245 1.841-.664 2.594l4.479.436C56.754 22 58 20.422 58 19.026v-2.742c0-2.062-2.017-4.055-3.59-2.985L51 16.325a5.32 5.32 0 0 1 .693 2.645"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                        </div>
                        GPU cards
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="downloads-documentation__item">
                    <a class="downloads-documentation__reference" id="item_3" href="" target="_blank">
                        <div class="downloads-documentation__image">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="72" viewBox="0 0 75 72">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="164.2%" height="168%" x="-32.1%" y="-34%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.699655813 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#05E2C2" transform="translate(11 11)">
        <circle cx="14.5" cy="7.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="45.5" cy="25.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="7.5" cy="35.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="5" cy="20" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="39" cy="11" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="30" cy="46" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="24" cy="25" r="5" fill="#05E2C2" stroke-width="4"></circle>
        <path stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="2" d="M18.667 14L22 20M9.208 22.213L19 25M36 14l-7 7.775M38 26.75H28M28 41.768l-3-12.652M14.318 32.286l6.47-4.048"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="72" viewBox="0 0 75 72">
    <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="164.2%" height="168%" x="-32.1%" y="-34%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0.0196078431 0 0 0 0 0.88627451 0 0 0 0 0.760784314 0 0 0 0.699655813 0"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#05E2C2" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(11 11)">
        <circle cx="14.5" cy="7.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="45.5" cy="25.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="7.5" cy="35.5" r="7.5" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="5" cy="20" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="39" cy="11" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="30" cy="46" r="4" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="24" cy="25" r="5" fill="#05E2C2" stroke-width="4"></circle>
        <path stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="2" d="M18.667 14L22 20M9.208 22.213L19 25M36 14l-7 7.775M38 26.75H28M28 41.768l-3-12.652M14.318 32.286l6.47-4.048"></path>
    </g>
</svg>

                        </div>
                        Command Line Node
                    </a>
                </li>
                    </ul>
```